# Run Word Macro from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I currently have a macro in excel that allows me to select a word document to open, and then select a table to import. But this macro does not format the table correctly in excel, split cells. Ideally, I wish I could just fix this macro, but I can't find out how.

```
Sub ImportWordTable()
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files ,*.doc;*.docx;*.docm", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
    TableNo = wdDoc.TAbles.Count
    If TableNo = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
        vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
    ElseIf TableNo > 1 Then
        TableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & TableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
        "Enter table number of table to import", "Import Word Table", "1")
    End If
    With .TAbles(TableNo).Range.Copy
Range("A1").Activate
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteSourceFormatting"
    End With
End With

Set wdDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

So I have a new script (in Word) that formats the table the way I want and copies it to clipboard, with a next macro in excel to paste from the clipboard.

Anyways, what i want to do is:
1) open word document by selection from excel
2) auto run macro once the word document is open
3) exit word and return to excel where I will call the next macro in the series.

Any ideas??

```
Sub RunWordMacroExe()
Dim oWFile As String
wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files ,*.doc;*.docx;*.docm", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")

wordApp.ActiveDocument.CopyTableForExcel
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the `Application.Run` method that lets you execute a macro?

Comment: Yes; My problem is just putting it into the code

Comment: Then show us what you've tried with it and explain HOW it "doesn't work".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't execute word macro from excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51067840/cant-execute-word-macro-from-excel)