# Can't execute word macro from excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I simply cannot get this to work. I am trying to run a word Macro from excel (before importing a table). Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RunWdMacro()

  Dim WordApp As Word.Application
  Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
  Dim wdFileName As Variant
  Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

  wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files ,*.doc;*.docx;*.docm", , _
    "Browse for file containing table to be imported")
  WordApp.Visible = True
  'change TEST to the name of your macro in word
  WordApp.Run "Delcolumnbreaks"

  WordApp.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
  Set WordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I am prompting for a word file to open, but it errors out at:

```
 WordApp.Run "Delcolumnbreaks"
```

With error "Run-time error '-2147352573 (800200003) Can't run the specified macro. The macro is in the normal section as module 1

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Where's `Delcolumnbreaks` defined? In a standard procedural module? Is it `Public`? Try qualifying it with the module name, e.g. `Module1.Delcolumnbreaks`. If the macro is written in a document module, or in some class module, then it's not a macro. Move it to a standard module.

Comment: I tried running with module1.delcolumbreaks but that did not work either.I have it under Normal in project in word....i am not sure the reference to standard module, but im a beginner

Comment: Okay but give us something now - your question is unanswerable without knowing where the macro is written in, what it's called, and how accessible it is.

Comment: "I have it under Normal in project in word" - see *that* is *the* critical piece of information that's missing from your post (you should [edit] your question to include this information). `Normal.dot` is just a document template that Word opens at start-up, *it's not the document you're opening*. It's also a document module, i.e. an object, which isn't where a macro is written in. Right-click the project, add module (.bas), cut the procedure from Normal and paste it in that module, then save.

Comment: ok, thank you. I will update

Comment: in addition, this document is huge. Is there a way to only execute this macro after the word file has finished opening?

Comment: VBA code runs synchronously. The instruction that follows the opening of the document will run after the `Open` method has returned. That said, Your code gets a filename to open, but doesn't *actually* open the selected file.

Comment: Ah I see, so the code has already "ran" before I actually open the file? The reason I have it where I can select the file to open and then run the script, is because the filename will never be the same, so I can't hard code that in

Comment: Yes I know that. What I'm saying is that `GetOpenFileName` prompts for a filename, but doesn't *open* the file. There's no instruction in your code that *opens the file* - so even if the macro existed in that file, Word couldn't run it, because the host document isn't even open

Comment: Gotcha. Can you advise on how to fix this disconnect?

Comment: You need `WordApp.Open wdFileName` somewhere between the part that prompts for a filename (and heck, validate if it's a valid one, too!), and the part that attempts to run the macro.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help!